# Poner un hiperenlace a una celda entera en html

Tags: html

Tengo el siguiente código html:

```
<html>
    <body bgcolor="#000000">
        <table width="100%" height="100%">
            <tr>
                <th width="20%" height="30%" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center" background="imagenes\Captura de pantalla 2022-11-16 132450.png" colspan="1"><a href="index.html"></a></th>
                <th colspan="1" rowspan="1"><font color="#FFFFFF">BIENVENIDO\A ATENCION AL CLIENTE</font></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><font color="#FFFFFF">EMAIL</font></th>
                <td><font color="#FFFFFF">Este es nuestro email de contacto anthonyshop@anthonyshop.es</font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><font color="#FFFFFF">TELEFONO</font></th>
                <td><font color="#FFFFFF">Este es nuestro telefono de contacto 666 66 88 99</font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><font color="#FFFFFF">TRABAJA CON NOSOTROS</font></th>
                <td><font color="#FFFFFF">Esta es nuestra direccion donde puedes venir para darnos tu curricukum y evaluaremos tu contratacion Calle tremendos trocolocos numero 13</font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="3"><font color="#FFFFFF">INFORMACION</font></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font color="#FFFFFF">Telefono: 666 66 88 99</font></td>
                <td width = "30%"><font color="#FFFFFF">Email: anthonyshop@anthonyshop.es</font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font color="#FFFFFF">Empresa: Tremendos SL</font></td>
                <td width = "40%"><font color="#FFFFFF">Direccion: Calle tremendos trocolocos numero 13</font></td>
            </tr>      
        </table>
        </body>
</html>
```

Me gustaría saber cómo en esta parte:

```
<tr>
    <th width="20%" height="30%" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center" background="imagenes\Captura de pantalla 2022-11-16 132450.png" colspan="1"><a href="index.html"></a></th>
```

se puede poner un hiperenlace a toda la celda completa para que cuando alguien pinche en la celda le lleve al enlace.

PD: no quiero añadir texto a la celda, solo quiero mantener la foto en esa posición.

[image: codigo]

Comment: Lo hago por un ejercicio de clase por eso no puedo utilizar css y nos han indicado que no pasa nada si no se valida

Comment: te refieres a un hipervínculo o sea donde des click y te redireccione a una página de tu proyecto o alguna otra página de internet

Comment: Si a donde de click me redireccione a una pagina de mi proyecto

Comment: Ponle un atributo `onclick=`  a la celda con un [location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href) de javascript, y si no te sale actualiza la pregunta con lo que has intentado y te corregimos

Comment: No puedo utilizar java script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más normal sería trasladar la imagen al anchortag, usando `img ... src`.  Por ejemplo:

```html
<tr>
  <th width="20%" height="30%" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center" colspan="1">
    <a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" alt="Image" /></a>
  </th>
</tr>
```

Comment: Esta si me ha funcionado lo malo es que he tenido que poner el hiperenlace en la foto como tal mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de poder poner el enlace en la celda

Comment: @Anthonyx82 ¿esto es un ejercicio? Lo que quieres hacer es contrario al estándar. Una celda es un contenedor, y deberías aplicar las cosas sobre lo que la celda contiene, no sobre la celda en sí misma. Si lo piensas bien, uno no anda haciendo clicks sobre celdas o sobre filas, sino sobre los elementos que hay en ellas. Es como cuando hay texto en una celda, haces click en el texto, no en la celda. En el caso de la imagen es lo mismo, haces click sobre la imagen, no sobre la celda. No le veo demasiado sentido a querer clickear sobre la celda en sí misma para ir a un enlace.

Comment: Ya no tiene mucho sentido pero lo suyo seria eso poder poner el enlace en la celda y que la foto se quede de fondo e la celda

Comment: @Anthonyx82 no, *lo suyo* sería hacer click **sobre lo que contiene la celda**, no sobre la celda en sí misma. Imagina una celda donde tengas varias cosas y quieras tratar esas cosas de manera distinta. Como dije antes, la celda es un contenedor.

Comment: De todos modos, si quieres poner el enlace en la celda, puedes usar `onclick`, como te ha sugerido @masterguru, y OJO: eso no es Javascript, `onclick` es uno de los atributos HTML posibles para un elemento `th` o `td` [como podrás ver en w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6).

Comment: Pero no hay ninguna forma de poder hacer click sobre la celda osea sobre el contenedor entero?

Comment: Le puedes poner el atributo `onclick`, @Anthonyx82, esa es la forma más sencilla. Es importante entender que para un enlace tú necesitas un elemento `a` y no es normal que `a` contenga a `td`, debería ser lo contrario, por lo dicho más arriba en comentarios. O, puedes lograrlo de otro modo, pasando por trucos vía `.css`, todo para alterar el orden natural de las cosas. Como ejercicio podría estar OK, pero no sería nunca un código estandarizado.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes envolver el `th` dentro de la etiqueta `a` para obtener el resultado que buscas.

```
<a href="index.html">
  <th width="20%" height="30%" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center" background="imagenes\Captura de pantalla 2022-11-16 132450.png" colspan="1"></th>
 </a>
```

Comment: no me funciona  aun asi

Comment: Si no te funciona, es posible que tengas un problema de enrutamiento. Revisa si el archivo `index.html` está en la misma carpeta, al mismo nivel del archivo que contiene tu tabla.

Comment: mira edito mi pregunta para que veas una foto de los directorios

Comment: Prueba con `./index.html` aunque debería ser lo mismo.

Comment: No tampoco funciona aunque ponga ./index.html

Comment: Supongo que no habra ninguna forma de poner un hiperenlace en una celda como tal

Comment: Si es posible... de la manera que te indico en la respuesta. Esto solo aplica a manera de ejercicio, ya que como te indica @a.cedano, no es el estándar.

Comment: Una recomendación adicional, **no utilices nombres de rutas o archivos con espacios en blanco**, en su lugar usa camelCase, PascalCase o snake_case